# Merge two collections using streams, but only unique values, and using predicate instead of equals?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, java-9

I'm trying to **merge** two collections, but do it **conditionally** where I only want to add **unique** values. And what constitutes **uniqueness** should be decided by a **predicate** (or similar), not the **equals** function.

For example, let's assume we have the following two collections of Person objects:

```
List<Employee> list1 = Arrays.asList(new Employee(1, "Adam", "Smith", Type.CEO), new Employee(2, "Bob", "Jones", Type.OfficeManager), new Employee(3, "Carl", "Lewis", Type.SalesPerson));

List<Employee> list2 = Arrays.asList(new Employee(4, "Xerxes", "Brown", Type.OfficeManager), new Employee(5, "Yuri", "Gagarin", Type.Janitor), new Employee(6, "Zain", "Wilson", Type.SalesPerson));
```

...and lets assume that I want to merge these lists into a new list by adding elements from both list1 and list2, but excluding elements that have an corresponding "identical" person object already added to the new list, and where the uniqueness is determined by the Type enum (Type.CEO, Type.OfficeManager etc).

Then the expected result, after the merge, is a new list that contains the following persons:

```
Employee(1, "Adam", "Smith", Type.CEO)
Employee(2, "Bob", "Jones", Type.OfficeManager)
Employee(3, "Carl", "Lewis", Type.SalesPerson)
Employee(5, "Yuri", "Gagarin", Type.Janitor)
```

What would be the "best" way to achieve this, in a general **Java 8/9** way? Ie I don't want to write something that is specific to Person objects or the Type enum, and I don't want to write something that uses the equals method of the objects. Instead I would like to use a **BiPredicate** or something similar.

But also, I would like not having to perform any looping myself. **Streams** seems like a good choice, but I can't figure out how to achieve this. How can I write a BiPredicate where one value comes from one stream and the other value comes from another stream, without performing the looping myself?

The reason I want to use an BiPredicate (or similar) is that I want to be able to use this function with advanced logic, where it is not possible to simply extract some property of all the elements, and then group the values based on the uniqueness of this property.

Any suggestions?

/Jimi

***Update:*** To clarify why I talk about a predicate, here is a more complex example:

Lets assume that we have the two collections of Employee objects as before. But this time the uniqueness logic can't be expressed using a mapping function to a specific property of the Employee object. Instead it uses some data in the EmployeeRegistry, like this: *if two employees belong to the same tax bracket **or** if they are of the same "type" then they are considered equal*. Because of this OR-logic it is not possible to reduce this to a unique key to use in grouping the data or something like that.

***Update2***: For the sake of simplicity, below is a less complex example, but that still is complex enough to not be a simple mapping to a field. It is a bit contrived, but that is for the sake of simplicity.

Lets assume that we have the two collections of Strings. And uniqueness is calculated like this:

- If two strings are of equal length, they are considered equal
- Otherwise, if two strings start with the same character, they are considered equal

Using the method **Collectors.toMap**, as suggested by **Federico Peralta Schaffner**, seems to work, although I'm not sure how I can write an `hashCode()` implementation that follows the standard and at the same time is efficient. The only functional implementation I can think of is one that returns a constant value (ie the same value regardless of the string).

***Update 3***: Considering that the **OR-logic** of my "equalness" algorithm breaks the **equals contract**, and makes it difficult (impossible?) to write an effective hashCode implementation, I am now back where I started. Ie needing something like a **predicate** of some sort. Here is an updated, "real world" example:

Lets assume that we have the two collections of Employee objects as before, and we want to merge these collections into one. But this time we want to avoid including people that don't get along. To determin if two people get along, we have an HumanRelationsDepartment object, with the method isOkToWorkWithEachother(Person, Person). When two people that don't get along is detected, then only of of them is to be added to the new collection. Which one can be determined by a mapping function, and the default logic could be that the first person is selected.

It is rather trivial to write old school code that solves this problem. What I'm looking for is a loop-free stream based solution. Does such a solution exist? Performance is not an issue.

Comment: A predicate is not a good input for this kind of task, as it would unavoidably require to test all *n×m* combinations (all elements of the first list with all elements of the other lists). And that’s under the assumption that the incoming lists are free of duplicates, as otherwise, the even worse need for *(n+m)²* tests becomes unavoidable.

Comment: *"I don't want to write something that uses the equals method of the objects"* why?

Comment: It would narrow the steps down to collecting in a set.

Comment: @Andrew I want to be able to change the uniqueness logic without having to change the equals method, and more specifically I want to be able to use multiple different uniqueness implementations in different parts of the same program for the same type of object. Think of it as having various Comparator implementations for different views of the object.

Comment: @Andrew also... I would like to be able to use this method with Collection<SomeInterface>, where the actual objects are of various different types (ie not suitable for the equals method).

Comment: @Holger then what other options are available, in order to achieve the general solution I write about in the update of the question?

Comment: The best option is still a function which returns a key object representing the relevant properties. If you want to compare lengths, just return the length as `Integer`. If you want to compare common prefixes, just return the relevant substring. If you want to consider multiple properties, return an object composed of those properties. Your “OR-logic” does not work, as it would not be transitive. You could have `a == b` due to “same tax bracket” and `b == c` because of “the same ‘type’” while `a != c` because neither, “same tax bracket” nor “the same ‘type’”.

Comment: @Holger What do you mean with "your OR-logic doesn't work"? This is the business use case I want to solve. When I wrote "considered equal" it was a more generic term than that of the equals method. But instead of talking about "equalness" I maybe should talk about "similarity" or "having something in common", or something similar. See update 3 above.

Comment: The point is, you need to specify what should happen when you encounter the situation that `a == b` and `b == c` but `a != c` due to the two different criteria. Should only one of `a`, `b`, or `c` be kept? Well then, it’s easy. Just use functions as described before and two passes, first eliminate all duplicates according to criteria1, then eliminate all duplicates according to criteria2. That’s still way more efficient than performing *n×m* predicate evaluations.

Comment: "Should only one of a, b, or c be kept?"

Well, that depends on the mapping function provided. It could be that both a and c will remain.


"That’s still way more efficient than performing n×m predicate evaluations."

So? Efficiency is not always important. Maybe the number of items is very low (like below 100), and the logic is not called often.

Answer (score 2):

For a simple merging of the two streams, you can use concat (just update reducer's logic):

```
Collection<Employee> merged = Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(emp -> emp.getType(),
                                   Collectors.reducing(null, (e1, e2) -> e1 ) ))
    .values();
```

---

For element-wise merging of the 2 collections (assuming same length), you can use an index-based integer stream, to simulate a `zipping` of the two lists, then use a reducer that merges the two into one.

*1 - Ensure lists are sorted by type, as that's what determines uniqueness:*

```
List<Employee> list1Sorted = list1.stream()
       .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getType))
       .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Employee> list2Sorted = list2.stream()
       .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getType))
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

*2 - Declare a "reducer" that will merge 2 objects at the same index:*

```
//This is returning an arbitrary value. You may want to add your own logic:
BiFunction<Employee, Employee, Employee> reducer = (e1, e2) -> e1;
```

*3 - Now assume lists have the same length and simulate a `zip` operation:*

```
List<Employee> mergedList = IntStream.range(0,  list1.size())
    .mapToObj(i -> new Employee[] {list1Sorted.get(i), list2Sorted.get(i)})
    .map(e -> reducer.apply(e[0], e[1]))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

To simplify it: make a generic `zip` method:

```
public static <T> List<T> zipStreams(List<T> list1, List<T> list2, BiFunction<T, T, T> employeeMerger, Comparator<T> sortComparator) {

    if(list1.size() != list2.size()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Lists must be of the same length");
    }

    List<T> list1Sorted = sortComparator == null ? list1: list1.stream()
                    .sorted(sortComparator)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()), 
       list2Sorted = sortComparator == null ? list2: list2.stream()
                    .sorted(sortComparator)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return IntStream.range(0,  list1Sorted.size())
            .mapToObj(i -> Arrays.<T>asList(list1Sorted.get(i), list2Sorted.get(i)))
            .map(list -> employeeMerger.apply(list.get(0), list.get(1)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Obviously, this is very specific to *merging employee lists element-wise*.

Now we can call that with:

```
zipStreams(list1, list2, (e1, e2) -> e1, Comparator.comparing(Employee::getType));
```

Comment: So... what if I want to keep the original order of the objects, and the lists are of unequal size?

Comment: @j5423951 Last edit happens to use the comparator optionally. Regarding different lengths: also added a simple merge that groups on type. Just make sure the reducer implements your logic of merging 2 employees into 1

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you want by means of [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)):

```
Collection<Employee> merged = Stream.of(list1, list2)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> calculateGroup(e), e -> e, (e1, e2) -> e1)))
    .values();
```

So this creates a `Map<SomeGroupType, Employee>`, according to some `calculateGroup` method that receives an `Employee` instance and returns something that represents the group which the `Employee` belongs to. This could be some property of the `Employee`, i.e. `type`, or something more complicated that could get data from somewhere else to determine the group, i.e. tax bracket, as per the employee's annual income. This is for the key of the map, which will determine the *uniqueness* according to your specific needs. The only requirement of this approach is that whatever class you use for the keys, it must implement `equals` and `hashCode` consistently.

The values of the map will be just the `Employee` instances of the concatenated streams. For the *merge function* (`Collectors.toMap` 3rd argument), I've used `(e1, e2) -> e1`, meaning that we'll keep the values already present in the map when there are equal keys. If you want to overwrite values instead, change it to `(e1, e2) -> e2`.

Comment: Thanks for the example code. Although I am struggling with the hashCode implementation. See update2 of the question. How would you implement the hashCode function for this SomeGroupType class?

Comment: @j5423951 Your example of `equals` in your update 2 is not transitive, so it violates the `Object.equals` contract, i.e. take strings `a = "abc"`, `b = "123"` and `c = "12"`, in this case `a.equals(b)` is `true` and `b.equals(c)` is `true` as well, however `a.equals(c)` is `false`.

Comment: Well that means that I can't use equals-logic then... Ie I can't create some wrapper object for the interesting properties. That means I'm back where I started, having to use some sort of predicate.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Concatenate the streams
Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream())
    .collect(
        // Collect similar employees together
        groupingBy(
            // Where "similar" is determined by a function, e.g. Employee::getType
            keyFn,
            // Take the first employee found
            (a, b) -> a)
    // Discard the keys.
    .values();
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems similar to the solution that Jonathan suggested, but with code example as well. And it also assumes that the uniqueness of two objects can be determined by just looking at one property of the objects. That was just an example in my original post.

Comment: @j5423951 not really; it can be any function, not just of one field.

Comment: well it still requires some mapping function. What if I need to use a completely external logic to determine equalness? See my updated question for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Map them to a map with the unique value as the key, and then map the entries to a list.

Comment: Is this what you mean?

Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream()).collect(Collectors.toMap(mappingFunctionForUniqueness, t -> t)).values();

Seems to work, for the simple use case in my example. But what about the more complex use case? Ie where I want to use some custom logic to determine if two objects are considered "equal". Basically a BiPredicate, that you ask "are X and Y to be considered equal?", and it answers true/false.